# MySQL on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP save same value for all records

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table named `test_table` like below:
https://ibb.co/QN8f328
I've set for the `updated_dt` column on update event is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

But when new rows insert in to table, the value of `updated_dt` column is not change and not `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value, like this 
https://ibb.co/Jvb7zcw

What went wrong? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

change to

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and use query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, updated_dt = now(), ...
```

suggestion only :D

Answer (score 0):

When you update whole table which has fewer records the update will be in fraction of seconds.

That is why you are seeing same date_time in `updated_dt` all for the rows.

If you try to do a manual update in the table,

for example:

**Query:**

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET request_status = 'TEST'
WHERE id = 193;
```

Then you can see change in the `updated_dt` column which will be your current_timestamp.

> *But when new rows insert in to table, the value of updated_dt column is not change and not CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value*

This is because you have set `current_timestamp` for both `created_dt` & `updated_dt`,

So what basically does is when you insert it will store `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in both the columns. And when you update that row now only the `updated_dt` column will change.

**Options:**

There is another option `NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can set this as a default in your `updated_dt`column.

What it does is, When inserting new records into the `test_table` only `created_dt` column has `current_timestamp` value and `updated_dt` will be `NULL`. Once you update the column now you can see current_timestamp in `updated_dt`.